# Logistic Regression in R with the nlstools package or with a glm?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I had a statistic class where a Logistic Regression was set up on some ecotoxicological data (dose-response curve) and the nlstools package was used for this purpose. So far when I came across the Logistic Regression I only used the glm and I am not sure what is the difference between these two approaches. When applying both approaches on the same data there was a clear difference between the fitted curves.

I already tried to look for answers but what I've read so far is that the nlstools package is used for nonlinear Regressions. From what I've read the Logistic Regression is not really a nonlinear Regression but a gerneralized linear model. Why can you use the nlstools package then? And I am a little bit confused how I should classify the Logistic Regression. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a crucial difference between logistic regression (a generalized linear model with the binomial distribution family) and fitting the logistic function using non-linear least-squares. I suggest you google some keywords from the preceding sentence.

Comment: This question boils down to 'What is the difference between logistic regression and non-linear regression." I think this is less of a coding question, but more of a statistical question. Hence I think this question should be moved to Stats Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I am pretty new to stackoverflow but I will post questions like that in another section next time